# Did I post a question about an induction proof of the Multinomial Theorem?

Tags: support

Please forgive me, but I can't recollect if I posted such a question that might have been subsequently deleted? I don't know of a way to search for any old, deleted question (and not simply recently deleted ones), so would a moderator or +10k user please help?

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/53259 indicates 'No deleted recent questions'.

Comment: You seem to have only deleted (in this case: self-deleted) question on main, called "Intuition: Commutativity of Real Numbers". Nothing about the multinomial theorem.

Comment: In your profile page, in the questions tab, there's a link at the bottom, recently deleted questions. Try there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you. Are you referring to the link which I just added to my OP?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thanks. Am I able to see that (self-)deleted post, or are only moderators able?

Comment: @LePressentiment You can try: It is the very last question when one sorts your questions according to votes.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks. I don't see it though.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Would you please check if there were comments after my recent deletion (which I just reversed) of this question? Someone suggested `deleted:yes is:question`?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A53259+deleted%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks, but the link displays 151 results (all my questions)?

Comment: @LePressentiment Not for me. Maybe the unavailable option to view deleted question gets supressed by users with rep <10k?